# How to capture all visited URLs on the command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, firefox, chromium, pipe

I like to get all URLs I visit in the browser live captured on the command-line for piping them to another program. How would I be able to do this?

The format should be just one URL per line, nothing else, no tabs, no spaces etc.

This is what I have got so far. The tab removal is not working. [I have seen a comment replying to someone](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Web+Traffic+Analysis+with+httpry/9295) (at the very bottom) who not had problems with piping it to grep that he should escape it. I not really understand this.

```
sudo httpry -F -i eth0 -f host,request-uri | tr -d 't'
```

Also even if this works it will not work with https right? Is there another way to do this that includes https? I am willing to use browser plugins for firefox and chromium if they exist. Just want to send all visited URLs to a script.

Maybe I can parse the browsers historys live and pipe that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Network traffic capturing is possible but messy. There are many applications running on my computer that communicate over HTML and they would *fill* a log up with their automated API handling and wouldn't reflect what *I* was visiting.

And as you correctly say, it won't show you HTTPS. The URL is an encrypted part of the request.

I would target the browser directly. These keep a decent enough history in a SQLite3 database which makes querying them pretty simple once you have the sqlite3 package installed (`sudo apt-get install sqlite3`). You can simply run:

```
sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/places.sqlite "select url from moz_places order by last_visit_date desc limit 10;"
```

And that will output the last 10 URLs you visited.

Chrome has a similar setup and can be queried equally simply:

```
sqlite3 ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/History "select url from urls order by last_visit_time desc limit 10;"
```

This works but I had some database locking issues with Chrome. It seems much more reliable in Firefox. The only way around the database lock I found was to make a copy of the database. This works even when the main DB is locked up and shouldn't cause issues:

```
cp ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/History history.tmp
sqlite3 history.tmp "select url from urls order by last_visit_time desc limit 10;"
rm history.tmp
```

This approach might even be advisable for Firefox too. FF doesn't appear to lock (or takes shorter locks) but I'm not sure what would happen if you caught it mid-write.

---

To turn this into a *live* display, it's either something you would need to poll (it's not that involved a SQL query, so that might be fine) or use something like `inotifywait` to monitor the database file for changes.

Comment: Thanks, still like to know how to avoid this issues with chrome. Otherwise this not feels complete enough for me to accept this.

Comment: @redanimalwar You can copy the database file out for Chrome to circumvent the lock. I've tested this and it works.

Comment: Ok I guess since I have to watch the file for changes anyway to run the command all over again, i might as well copy it after it changed.