# Chromium Incognito urls visit see in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromium

I visited few urls in incognito mode in chromium (ubuntu 14.04). now I have closed the incognito window so I can't see visited urls in chromium's history section. but I was wondering if chromium itself save those urls in some file in hidden mode or something similar.

or even system(ubuntu) itself keeps track of all visited urls from all browsers, you know all networking stuff.

I looked at this thread  [How to capture all visited URLs on the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438396/how-to-capture-all-visited-urls-on-the-command-line)

but couldn't find the incognitos urls.

is it possible to find last privately visited urls?

Comment: There is the zeitgeist project which tracks user-activities. But this needs extensions for the related apps as far as i know and i doubt that it tracks the incognito mode. This comment is just to point you into the zeitgeist direction for further search by yourself.

Comment: Try to ask your ISP about it. Chrome and Ubuntu don't keep this info by default.

Comment: To see browse history is `$ sqlite3 ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/History "select url from urls order by last_visit_time desc limit 1000;"` For here, you may find where the Icognito folder located and replace the with that.